# Google fonts API causes flicker with jquery fade

Tags: jquery, fonts

I'm using the Google Fonts API on a page with jQuery 1.7.2.  I simply add my nice font with:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Marmelad' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

I then use jQuery to fadeout a div, load() a second HTML file into the div and fade it in.  Everything works fine.

The problem is any Marmelad (my google font) text on the page will flicker at the end of the fadein transition.  If I simply change the same Marmelad text to Arial or some other stock font the flicker does not happen.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

This is how I fadeout/in the div.

```
jQuery("#clickme").click(function() { 
jQuery('#secondarybox').fadeOut('fast', function() {   
jQuery('#secondarybox').load('nextstep.html', function() { 
jQuery('#secondarybox').fadeIn('slow'); }); }); 
});
```

Again, there is no text flickering when I use Arial on the entire page, but if I use the Google Font all text flickers including text that is not involved in the transition/fading.

Answer (score 0):

this helped me:

```
$('.slider_container').fadeIn(function(){
    this.style.removeAttribute("filter");
});
```

it is solution only for IE. I'am stuck with same problem in Chrome.